# How can I combine the print data from two separate for statements?

Tags: python, for-loop, printing, python-requests, request

I have a list of data and would like to print both "number" and "detail" on the same line. Currently the results print one after each other but I need the results to be on the same line.

```
for part in parts:

    number = part.text
    print(number)

for info in infos:

    detail = info.text
    print(detail)
```

Moving the print statement outside does not show all results, only the last result.

```
for part in parts:

    number = part.text

for info in infos:

    detail = info.text

print(number + detail)
```

How can I combine the data that is printed in these for statements?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `parts` and `infos` are of the same length:

```py
for part,info in zip(parts,infos):
    print(part.text + info.text)
```

If one is shorter then the other, the extra items in longer one will be clipped off.

In that case, you may check `itertools.zip_longest`